# Cloud, manipulate based on a external dataset

Tags: manipulate, import, wolfram-cloud

My question is about creating a Manipulate based on a external dataset (in my private Cloud) and publish it in the Public Cloud.

```
data = Import["filename.TXT","Table", {"FieldSeparators" -> "|", "CharacterEncoding" -> "ASCII","HeaderLines" -> 1, "EmptyField" -> "","RepeatedSeparators" -> False,"DateStringFormat" -> {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}}]
```

The output is:

> {{0,1,0,0,0,5},{1,1,1,1,1,297},{1,2,0,1,1,5},.......{1,3,1,1,1,1}}

The script for creating the manipulate is:

```
    man=Manipulate[
ListLinePlot[{Select[data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]], #[[1]] == Round[bonbedrag] &][[All, {2, 3}]],
Select[data[[All, {1, 2, 4}]], #[[1]] == Round[bonbedrag] &][[All, {2, 3}]],
Select[data[[All, {1, 2, 5}]], #[[1]] == Round[bonbedrag] &][[All, {2, 3}]]}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
FillingStyle ->  LightBrown,
PlotStyle -> {{Red, , Thick}, {Blue, Thick}, {Green, Dashed, Thick}},
PlotLegends ->
Placed[{"ondergrens", "bovengrens", "gemiddeld"}, Below],
InterpolationOrder -> 2,
AxesLabel -> {Style["aantal artikelen gekocht", Bold, Red],
Style["prijs duurste artikel", Bold, Blue]}, ImageSize -> Large,
PlotLabel ->
Style[Framed[StringForm["Bonbedrag = Euro " <> ToString[Round[bonbedrag]]]]],
GridLines -> Automatic,
GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Orange, Dashed],
PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 200}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}
],
{bonbedrag, 1, 200, 0.01},
Bookmarks -> {"start" :> (bonbedrag = 0),
"end" :> (bonbedrag = 200), "back" :> (bonbedrag = 0)},
SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Then I export this manipulate using CloutPut with the permissions Public

```
CloudPut[man, Permissions->"Public"]
```

You can see the result at:

```
CloudObject[https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/a2b420d3-9774-4ef8-b2f5-4a3214a6383e]
```

What you see is not the Manipulate but the original code. As far as I understand, the reason is the external dataset.

Anyone a suggestion how to solve this issue?

Thanks,
Michiel

Answer (score 1):

Using `With` and `CloudDeploy` (and an extra `Column` somehow) will do it:

```
man = With[{data = (* Import[ ... ] *)
      { {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 295}, {1, 2, 
       0, 1, 1, 5}}},

 Manipulate[
    Column[{"",
      ListLinePlot[{Select[
          data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]], #[[1]] == 
            Round[bonbedrag] &][[All, {2, 3}]], 
        Select[data[[All, {1, 2, 4}]], #[[1]] == 
            Round[bonbedrag] &][[All, {2, 3}]], 
        Select[data[[All, {1, 2, 5}]], #[[1]] == 
            Round[bonbedrag] &][[All, {2, 3}]]}, 
       Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, FillingStyle -> LightBrown, 
       PlotStyle -> {{Red, , Thick}, {Blue, Thick}, {Green, Dashed, 
          Thick}}, 
       PlotLegends -> 
        Placed[{"ondergrens", "bovengrens", "gemiddeld"}, Below], 
       InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
       AxesLabel -> {Style["aantal artikelen gekocht", Bold, Red], 
         Style["prijs duurste artikel", Bold, Blue]}, 
       ImageSize -> Large, 
       PlotLabel -> 
        Style[Framed[Row[{"Bonbedrag = Euro ", Round[bonbedrag]}]]], 
       GridLines -> Automatic, 
       GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Orange, Dashed], 
       PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 200}}, 
       AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]}], {bonbedrag, 1, 200, 0.01}, 
    Bookmarks -> {"start" :> (bonbedrag = 0), 
      "end" :> (bonbedrag = 200), "back" :> (bonbedrag = 0)}, 
    SaveDefinitions -> True]];
CloudDeploy[man, Permissions -> "Public"]
```

Comment: Hi Rolf, Can you more explicit about the part "data = (* Import[ ... ] *)" When I tried man = With[{data = Import["filename.TXT","Table", {"FieldSeparators" -> "|", "CharacterEncoding" -> "ASCII","HeaderLines" -> 1, "EmptyField" -> "","RepeatedSeparators" -> False,"DateStringFormat" -> {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}}]}], it failed.

Comment: @MichielvanMens it should just work. Maybe you have to give a full path name ?